# Core API Controller to catch all unknown routes

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing, .net-core-2.2

I have a Core 2.2 API with a bunch of existing controllers. What i am now trying to do is add a new controller that acts similar to a catchall route, but only for that controller *(and doesn't disturb the routes of the existing controllers)*.

In my existing controller i am defining the routes as controller attributes

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SandboxController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Hello")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Hello()
    {
        return new string[] { "Hello World", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time")).ToString()};
    }
}
```

For this new "catchall" controller **i need it to be able to catch any Get, Post, Put, Delete that is routed to it**. For example this controllers route is ../**api/catchall**. If someone where to do a post to ../api/catchall/**some/random/unknown/route** i'm trying to catch this and route it to ../api/catchall/**post**.

So far i have be utterly unsuccessful. This is what i got so far:

In my Startup.cs

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

...

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Sandbox}/{action=Hello}/{id?}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "catchall",
            template: "{controller}/{*.}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "catchall", action = "post" });
    });
```

And the catchall controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CatchallController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("post", Order = int.MaxValue)]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        return Content("{ \"name\":\"John Doe\", \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\" }", "application/json");
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how i can get this to work?

Comment: Did you try middleware for this? You can write your own custom middleware

Comment: If i gather correctly this is for the api  and not the entire app?

Comment: @avin correct, just this one controller.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Catch all routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-template-reference) are specified with the `*` or `**` syntax. Place `[Route("{**catchall}")]` on the action that you want to be the catch all action. This will make a catch all route for all routes prefixed with the prefix specified in the Controller route attribute.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CatchallController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("{**catchAll}")]
    [HttpPost("post", Order = int.MaxValue)]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value, string catchAll)
    {
        return Content("{ \"name\":\"John Doe\", \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\" }", "application/json");
    }
}
```

In the example above, this will catch `api/catchall/anything/following/it` and set the string catchAll to `anything/following/it`

If you want to set a site-wide catch all route you can use an absolute url

```
[Route("/{**catchAll}")]
public IActionResult CatchAll(string catchAll)
{

}
```

This will catch any route that does not match any other specified route.

Comment: So no need for the routing in the Startup config?

Comment: Dang, so simple... I was over thinking that by a mile! Thx

Comment: Note: this doesn't work with minimal API's

Comment: Huh. In .NET 6, the order parameter appears ignored and my catch all route executes first. Very odd.