# Is there a way to process requests with various amounts of slashes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing

I am writing an API Gateway and it's purpose is to redirect request to different microservices given that the user has access to it.

Let's assume my Gateway is running on port `7000`. For example, user is requesting `http://localhost:7000/foo/method/` and I see by looking in his JWT that he has access to microservice `foo`. In this case I make the request to appropriate URL (let's say `http://localhost:7001/method`) and return the body to user.

Another example, user is requesting `http://localhost:7000/baz/othermethod/somelink`, in this case I would redirect to something like `http://localhost:7002/othermethod/somelink`.

Point is: **I want to be able to accept and process requests with various amounts of slashes**, but I am not aware of a way to accomplish this or if this is even possible. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: Have you looked in to creating your own [middleware](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/)? There are [lots of examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=asp.net+core+middleware+c%23). [This](https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/) also looks interesting.

Comment: Have you looked at catch all routes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587342/core-api-controller-to-catch-all-unknown-routes

Comment: Thank you all for your wonderful answers! My team and I are looking into them at the moment. I think for the time being something like catch all routes will do nicely (thanks @ESG), however own middleware sounds good as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how far you are into building the gateway, It might be worth looking into something like [ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot). I've used it on some really large projects in the past, and the routing tables there should be able to handle what you're describing.